# $Tr(A^2)=Tr(A^3)=Tr(A^4)$ then find $Tr(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, trace

Let $A$ be a non singular $n\times n$ matrix  with all eigenvalues real and 
$$Tr(A^2)=Tr(A^3)=Tr(A^4).$$Find $Tr(A)$.

I considered $2\times 2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ and tried computing traces of $A^2,A^3,A^4$ and ended up with following

1. $Tr(A^2)=Tr(A)^2-2\det(A)$
2. $Tr(A^3)=Tr(A)^3-3Tr(A)\det(A)$
3. $Tr(A^4)=Tr(A)^4-4Tr(A)^2\det(A)+2\det(A)$

I have no idea how to proceed from here...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's denote the eigenvalues by $t_j$. Then, by Cauchy-Schwarz
$$
\sum t_j^3 \le \left( \sum t_j^2 \sum t_j^4\right)^{1/2} ,
$$
which equals $\sum t_j^3$ by assumption. Equality in the CSI means that the vectors are linearly dependent, so $t_j=ct_j^2$. This says that there is only one eigenvalue ($=1/c$), and clearly it must be $1$ then. So $\textrm{tr}\, A=n$.

Comment: Since $A$ is not assumed to be diagonalizable, you should say "generalized eigenvalues" instead of "eigenvalues".

Comment: What if $t_j=0$? $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: Because it is non singular $t_j\neq 0$ for any $j$  and so $t_j=\frac{1}{c}$right? @user1551

Comment: @user1551: $A$ is assumed to be nonsingular.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks. I've overlooked that part.

Comment: Yes, $t_j=0$ is ruled out by $A$ being non-singular; also, "eigenvalue" is the right word, whether $A$ is diagonalizable or not.

Comment: @EricWofsey : I do not understand your comment.. What is being diagonalizable has anything to do with eigenvalues

Comment: Well, if you call them "eigenvalues", you should say you are counting them by algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: I was wondering why $c$ has to be $1$.. Then i see that $t_i^3=t_it_i^2=ct_i^2t_i^2=ct_i^4$ and so $$Tr(A^3)=\sum t_i^3=\sum ct_i^4=c\sum t_i^4=cTr(A^4)$$ SO, $c=1$ as we have $Tr(A^3)=Tr(A^4)$

Answer (score 14):

A slightly different approach: we have $\operatorname{trace}((A-A^2)^2)=0$. As $A$ has a real spectrum, so does $A-A^2$. So, the previous trace condition implies that $A-A^2$ is nilpotent. Hence every eigenvalue of $A$ is equal to its square. As $A$ is nonsingular, every eigenvalue of $A$ must be equal to $1$. Hence the trace of $A$ is $n$.

Comment: So, you are saying if $Tr(A^2)=0$ then $A$ is nilpotent... I will check that and come back... Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @cello No, what I'm saying is that if $M$ is a real matrix ***with a real spectrum*** and $\operatorname{tr}(M^2)=0$, then $M$ is nilpotent.

Comment: i.e., if all eigenvalues are real and if trace of $M^2$ is zero then $M$ is nilpotent

Comment: Ok Ok... $t_i$ are eigenvalues of $M$ then $t_i^2$ are eigemvbalues of $M^2$ and then trace of $M^2$ is  $t_1^2+\cdots+t_n^2=0$ and $t_i\in \mathbb{R}$ implies $t_i=0$... So, $M$ is nilpotent

Comment: @user1551 Can you explain how did you know $\operatorname{trace}((A-A^2)^2)=0$? I didn't get that point.

Comment: @Quintic Expand $(A-A^2)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

we know that trace of a matrix is simply equal to the sum of all its eigen values.

Now, let all the eigen values of the matrix A of order n be as  a_1,a_2,a_3,.....,a_n

Also,we have an important result that for any square matrix A of order n , if  a is an eigen value of A then a^m is an eigen value of the matrix A^m ,for any positive integer m

Applying the above result,we get the following:

(a_1)^2,(a_2)^2,(a_3)^2,..........(a_n)^2 is the entire list of eigen values of the matrix  A^2

likewise,(a_1)^3,(a_2)^3,(a_3)^3,..........(a_n)^3 is the entire list of eigen values of the matrix  A^3

(a_1)^4,(a_2)^4,(a_3)^4,..........(a_n)^4 is the entire list of eigen values of the matrix  A^4

Now,from the given condition in the question,we have

(a_1)^2+(a_2)^2+(a_3)^2,..........+(a_n)^2 = (a_1)^3+(a_2)^3+(a_3)^3+..........+(a_n)^3 = (a_1)^4+(a_2)^4+(a_3)^3+..........+(a_n)^4      _______________(***)

Now, a_1,a_2,......,a_n are all real numbers(mentioned in pblm)

using the condition (***), we can easily deduce the relation

{a_1(a_1-1)}^2 + {a_2(a_2-1)}^2 + {a_3(a_3-1)}^2 +..........+{a_n(a_n-1)}^2 =0-_________________($$$)

which implies that each of the terms on L.H.S of the above equation equals 0 ,because each of the terms on L.H.S of the above eqn is a real no. and the sum of two or more real squares equals 0 iff each of them is individually 0

But,none of the eigen values of the matrix A is 0 because the det value of a matrix being equal to its product of eigen values would then become 0,contradiction to the given fact that A is non-singular

Hence,from equation($$$), we get that each eigen value of the matrix A is equal to 1.
So,trace of A = sum of all its eigen values = n (answer:)